# Alloy* does not stop solving in a very small higher-order space

Tags: alloy

I'm using Alloy* `hola-0.2.jar` to represent and study higher-order problems.
The following code 
`check isAR for 1 but exactly 1 Node, exactly 1 Edge` should fail with only one counterexample.

Yes, Alloy* finds the counterexample quickly. However, when I click "Next"  to try to find another counterexample, the solver **never** finish it. (I run this for at least 3 hours in my macbook pro.)

Indeed, by theory, no more counterexample exists. So Alloy* should state *No counterexample found. Assertion may be valid.* But, it never pop up.

I'm aware that solving higher-order problems requires more computational effort. However this problem of mine is very small. So I doubt my code. What's the problem?

```
// a Heyting Algebra of subgraphs of a given graph

sig Node {}
sig Edge {
    source: Node,
    target: Node}
fun Edge.proj : set Node { this.source + this.target}
pred isGraph[ns: set Node, es: set Edge] {es.proj in ns}

// Cmpl[sns,ses,cns,ces] means: a pseudo-complement of a subgraph s is a subgraph c.
pred Cmpl[sns: set Node, ses: set Edge, cns: set Node, ces: set Edge] { 
    !((cns!=none or ces!=none) and Node in sns and Edge in ses)
    Node in sns + cns
    Edge in ses + ces
    all ns: set Node | all es: set Edge when isGraph[ns,es] and (Node in sns + ns) and (Edge in ses + es)|
        (cns in ns and ces in es)
}

/* An element x of a Heyting algebra H is called regular 
 * if x = ¬y for some y in H. 
 */

pred isRegular [xns: set Node, xes: set Edge] {
    some yns: set Node | some yes: set Edge when isGraph[yns,yes]|
        one cyns: set Node | one cyes: set Edge |
            isGraph[cyns,cyes] and Cmpl[yns,yes,cyns,cyes] and (cyns=xns and cyes=xes)
}

assert isAR { // is always regular?
    all subns: set Node, subes: set Edge when isGraph[subns,subes] |
        isRegular[subns,subes]
} 

check isAR for 1 but exactly 1 Node, exactly 1 Edge 
// this should fail with 1 couterexample (by theory)
```

Comment: If I need to explain more about the problem it self (a Heyting algebra of subgraphs of a graph, pseudo-complement of a subgraph, etc), please let me know.

Comment: Can you try to assert in your model that you don't want to get the solution in question, and then see if the solver ever terminates with "no counterexample found"?   The implementation of the "Next" feature is a bit dodgy for higher-order models, so what I suggested here might be worth trying.